# Get max marks of each student in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Consider a table

| StudentId | Subject | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Maths | 34 |
| 1 | Science | 54 |
| 2 | Maths | 64 |
| 2 | French | 85 |
| 2 | Science | 74 |

I'm looking for an output where it will give (note that I'm trying to find MAX marks for each student, irrespective of the subject)

| StudentId | Subject | Marks |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Science | 54 |
| 2 | French | 85 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the summarize operator:

```
T
| summarize max(Marks) by StudentId
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to above query from @Avnera, if you also care about the corresponding subject in which the student received the maximum marks (*it seems like that based on your desired output table*), you can use the `arg_max` function:

```
T
| summarize arg_max(Marks, Subject) by StudentId
```

arg_max(): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/arg-max-aggfunction